# Неверный возврат ссылки на элемент, в чем проблема?

Tags: c++, xcode

При вводе, например, десятого элемента и попытке сменить его значение, меняет 3ий элемент, при попытке сменить первый элемент может сменить 4ый, выходит какой-то рандом, в чем проблема?

```
int &change(int i);
int vals[10];


int main(){

    int ch, newval;
    cout << "Enter your array.." << endl;
    for(int j = 0;j<10; j++) cin >> vals[j];

    cout << "\n" <<"Choose element which you want to change..  ";
    cin >> ch;
    cout << "Enter the new value for this element..  ";
    cin >> newval;
    newval = change(vals[ch-1]);
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) cout << vals[i] <<" "; // вывод массива


    return 0;
}

int &change(int k){

    return vals[k];
}
```

Comment: `change(ch-1) = newval;`

Comment: И еще - стоит инициализировать переменную `i` в цикле `for (int i; i<10; i++)`

Comment: Ну и если она примет "мусорное" значение 15 при входе в цикл - что вы увидите?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте в функцию индекс элемента, а не значение из массива:

```
change(ch-1) = newval;
```